# Using groupby() with appending additional rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

With the following csv input file

```
ID,Name,Metric,Value
0,K1,M1,200
0,K1,M2,5
1,K2,M1,1
1,K2,M2,10
2,K2,M1,500
2,K2,M2,8
```

This code, groups the rows by the name column, e.g. two groups. Then it appends the values as columns for the same Name.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=['ID','Name','Metric','Value'])
print(df)
my_array = []
for name, df_group in df.groupby('Name'):
    my_array.append( pd.concat(
        [g.reset_index(drop=True) for _, g in df_group.groupby('ID')['Value']],
        axis=1) )
print(my_array)
```

The output looks like

```
   ID Name Metric  Value
0   0   K1     M1    200
1   0   K1     M2      5
2   1   K2     M1      1
3   1   K2     M2     10
4   2   K2     M1    500
5   2   K2     M2      8
[   Value
0    200
1      5,    Value  Value
0      1    500
1     10      8]
```

For example, `my_array[1]` which is K2 has two rows corresponding to M1 and M2. I would like to keep the IDs as well in the final data frames in `my_array`. So I want to add a third row and save it (M1, M2 and ID). Therefore, the final `my_array` should be

```
[   Value
0    200
1      5
2      0,    Value  Value
0      1    500              <-- For K2, there are two M1 (1 and 500)
1     10      8              <-- For K2, there are two M2 (10 and 8)
2      1      2]             <-- For K2, there are two ID (1 and 2)
```

How can I modify the code for that purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for DataFrames pe groups and then append `df1.columns` in `np.vstack`:

```
my_array = []
for name, df_group in df.groupby('Name'):
    df1 = df_group.pivot('Metric','ID','Value')
    my_array.append(pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df1, df1.columns])))
print (my_array)
[     0
0  200
1    5
2    0,     0    1
0   1  500
1  10    8
2   1    2]
```